How to pass data from legacy ASP.NET MVC application to React?
I want to pass data from a legacy ASP.NET MVC application to React which will be in separate repository and deployed in different servers. I need some ways to achieve this. IFrame is not recommended to use.
I am expecting to pass data from the ASP.NET MVC application to the React application.
